# Oracle 12c - how to create a new table form existing table with all data, partitions and indexes like in first table?

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

Table t1 is partitioned and has data.

I am using this command to transfer data from t1 to t2:

```
CREATE TABLE t2
TABLESPACE ts1
  AS 
select * from t1;
```

However this copies all the data but does not create partitions as in t1. Is there a command to copy all the data plus partitions and indexes from t1 to t2?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_dbms_metadata.htm. I hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dbms_metadata` to get the whole structure.

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TABLE', 'SOURCE_TABLE_NAME' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Run the `DDL` generated from this query replacing the table name with new table name.

If your source_table is in a different schema, then

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TABLE', 'SOURCE_TABLE_NAME', 'SOURCE_SCHEMA_NAME' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible in the same schema - it will fail with an object already exists error. If it is a different schema, then try this: 
export and import by renaming the table while importing to another schema.

Otherwise try with DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL.